# Nightmare with YouTube API and the playVideo to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I have tried to implement the YouTube API into my site, and it was working fine up until a few days ago, and after hours and hours of no progress, I have made a fiddle with a basic setup, and I can't get it to work when you have an iFrame already embedded in the page.

```
 var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('testplayer');
}
function playthevideo() {
    player.playVideo();
};
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.testing').on('click', playthevideo);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/parvavilla/GXC4e/

When you click the button, the console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<S> has no method 'playVideo'
```

Any ideas what I have done wrong in this fiddle?

Comment: Any errors in the error console?

Comment: @Pekka웃 The error is in the question.

Comment: When are you calling `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()`?

Comment: calling it like it is in the question (globally)

Comment: @Pekka웃 YouTube calls that automatically.  And, that part *is* working.

Comment: Well, are you sure it is working, seeing as `player` isn't getting initialized? (I can't see another reason for that error coming up)

Comment: @Pekka웃 `player` is initialized, but incorrectly.  See my answer for details.

Comment: @Brad it isn't initialized incorrectly, the docs say you can use an iFrame https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are already loading a video via iframe.  The API doesn't expect that.  What you need instead is just a normal container.  In your HTML:

```
<div id="testplayer"></div>
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
player = new YT.Player('testplayer', { videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE' });
```

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/GXC4e/2/

Comment: The YouTube API docs say you can use an iFrame https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player and I need to use it with an iframe

Comment: @user28240 The YouTube API replaces that div with an iframe immediately.  Are you sure that won't work for you?

Comment: The reason it won't work well is because the iFrame is embedded on multiple pages and the videoID is different every time, I would have to do Regex or similar to get the videoID and then make the API remove and then rebuild the iFrame, which sounds complicated and pointless (considering the docs say an iFrame is allowed)

Comment: @user28240 That doesn't make much sense.  If you simply don't use an iframe, and plug the video ID into JavaScript, I don't see what the problem is.  I don't know why the iframe isn't working for you, but it isn't, and the div works.

Comment: As I explained, I have to use the iframe embed code and not "plug in the video ID", there are reasons for it. I was simply asking for help as to why it doesn't work, when the docs say the way I am implementing should work (and I am sure it did a week ago)

Comment: @user28240 If it worked a week ago, you didn't change anything, and it doesn't work now, it's probably either a bug on YouTube's end, or a feature they've removed.  There is a lot of old documentation out there for all of Google's products.  If you're saying that you can't change your site to fix anything... I don't know what to tell you.